# Issues in merging of training data from different samples

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, data-science, train-test-split

I have two files of training data, each of which have been split individually as train and test split data. how do i extract training samples with the given files

I have four files

- file1: some features
- file2: some other features with a few columns
  common to file 1

Detailing with an example

file 1 columns - timestamp, event, outcome,

test 1 is a test data split from file 1,

file 2 columns - timestamp, usertype, eventduration, outcome,

test2 contains test data split from file 2.....

I couldnt merge the training data or test data when i do so, i either report loss of data(inner join) or ambiguous data (in case of outer join). I need to perform logistic regression with these two data

test 1 and test 2 are test data sets that have been individually stripped as test data from file 1 and file 2

I need to perform logistic regression on the training samples and test it with file 3 and file 4. I have problems in merging due to this individual splitting. Can somebody suggest some best possible overcome this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is too broad. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: What exactly have you tried codewise? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Hi - I will explain more here, file 1 columns - timestamp, event, outcome, test 1 is a test data split from file 1, file 2 coumns - timestamp, usertype, eventduration, outcome, test2 contains test data split from file 2..... I couldnt merge the training data or test data when i do so, i either report loss of data(inner join) or ambiguous data (in case of outer join). I need to perform logistic regression with these two data

Comment: Make this an edit to your questions rather than a comment. Provide code. See this here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve